# Как правильно переместить элемент массива в конец?

Tags: javascript

Нужно все элементы массива со значением 0 переместить в конец массива.

```
moveZeros([false,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"]) // returns[false,1,1,2,1,3,"a",0,0]
```

Именно в приведенном примере все работает хорошо, а вот когда есть 2 или больше нуля подряд, то возникает проблема.

```
moveZeros(["a",0,"b","c","d",1,1,3,1,9,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]) // returns["a", "b", "c", "d", 1, 1, 3, 1, 9, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Вот мой код:

```js
function moveZeros (arr) {
  arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
    if (item === 0) {
      arr.push(item);
      arr.splice(index, 1);
    }
  });
  return arr;
}
```

Если я правильно понял, то причиной такого поведения является смещение в счетчике, но я не знаю как решить эту проблему. Для удобства мой код на [CodePen](https://codepen.io/MarianVytak/pen/ZEbMORM?editors=0012)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const arr = [false,1,0,1,2,0,1,3,"a"];
function moveZeros(arr) {
    let upperBound = arr.length;
    for (let i = 0; i < upperBound; i++) {
        if (arr[i] === 0) {
            arr.push(0);
            arr.splice(i, 1);
            upperBound--;
            i--;
        }
    }
    return arr;
}
console.log(arr);
```

Если наткнулись на ноль, то просто искусственно приостанавливаем итератор на том же индексе (`i--`) и продолжаем исследование с него же.

`upperBound` нужен только для того, чтобы не катать массив до конца, ведь в конце мы копим нули. Получится в итоге один полный проход по массиву.

Comment: нет, вы в своем примере мутируете массив. Я сохранил исходное условие. Обновил ответ!

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. `return arr` забыл дописать)

Comment: Да, уже дописал. Но мутация входного параметра в функции - это в принципе так себе тема. Без мутации в один простой проход все решается.

Answer (score 0):

может просто посчитать кол-во нулей в вашем массиве пусть это будет число n, удалить из исходного массива все нули, и просто присоединить в конец исходного массива массив нулей длиной равной n

```
var sample_arr = ["a",0,"b","c","d",1,1,3,1,9,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0];

let move_zeros = function(arr) {
    var zeros = [];

    for (let i=0; i < sample_arr.length; i++) {
        if (sample_arr[i] == 0) {
            zeros.push(0)
            arr.splice(i, 1)
        }
    }

    arr.concat(zeros)

    return arr
}

console.log(move_zeros(sample_arr))
```

Comment: Хорошая идея, попробую сделать так, но все равно, интересно, есть ли правильное решение именно с таким вариантом который я начал.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function moveZeros(arr) {
  let filtered = arr.filter(el => el !== 0);
  return filtered.concat(Array(arr.length - filtered.length).fill(0));
}

console.log(moveZeros([false, 1, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 3, "a"])+'');
console.log(moveZeros(["a",0,"b","c","d",1,1,3,1,9,0,0,9,0,0,0,0,0,0,0])+'');
```